# Is there a limit on php file size

Tags: php, json

I created an API for data in a website.

This API creates a php file, which is put in a cache directory.
(Data are stored in an array and json_decode)

It works until my file weighs less than 5-6 Mo, after this size i have a white page.

Several possibilities come to mind

- Php limit size : i try to insert `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` but no
- JSON limit size
- Server limit size

I know my question is very "open" but any help will be appreciate

Comment: "*Mo*" = "*MB*"? Check your maximum execution time as well. Maybe it takes to long to generate the file.

Comment: Why are you saving PHP files that are 6 MB large?!

Comment: *It works until my file **weighs** less than 5-6 Mo*. On a bathroom scale? How can you even write 6 MBs of code in a single PHP code file?

Comment: Why are you not using a database?

Comment: I should have to ask if it's a good practice to store a lot of data in a single file, i could do differently if there's no solutions (store data day by day, ... or using database)